# Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: magento2, php-7.2

On Magento 2.3.2 I switched from php 7.1 to php 7.2. When I did I started getting this error-
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /chroot/home/html/app/code/WeltPixel/GoogleTagManager/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml on line 10

Here is the code-

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php if($this->isEnabled()) : ?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('WeltPixel\GoogleTagManager\Helper\Data'); ?>
    <?php
    $crosselProductsCollection = $this->getCrosselProductCollection();
    $productImpressions = [];

    if (count($crosselProductsCollection)) :
        $i = 1;
        foreach($crosselProductsCollection as $_product) :
            $crosselProduct = array();
            $crosselProduct['name'] = html_entity_decode($_product->getName());
            $crosselProduct['id'] = $helper->getGtmProductId($_product);
            $crosselProduct['price'] = number_format($_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue(), 2, '.', '');
            if ($helper->isBrandEnabled()) :
                $crosselProduct['brand'] = $helper->getGtmBrand($_product);
            endif;
            $crosselProduct['category'] = $helper->getGtmCategoryFromCategoryIds($_product->getCategoryIds());
            $crosselProduct['list'] = __('Crossel Products');
            $crosselProduct['position'] = $i;
            $productImpressions[] = $crosselProduct;
            $i++ ;
        endforeach;
    endif;

    if (count($productImpressions)) :
        $this->setEcommerceData('currencyCode', $this->getCurrencyCode());
        $this->setEcommerceData('impressions', $productImpressions);
        $this->setDataLayerOption('event', 'impression');
        $this->setDataLayerOption('eventCategory', 'Ecommerce');
        $this->setDataLayerOption('eventAction', 'Impression');
        $this->setDataLayerOption('eventLabel',  \WeltPixel\GoogleTagManager\Model\Api\Remarketing::ECOMM_PAGETYPE_CART);
    endif;

    if ($helper->isAdWordsRemarketingEnabled()):
        $remarketingData = [];
        $remarketingData['ecomm_pagetype'] = \WeltPixel\GoogleTagManager\Model\Api\Remarketing::ECOMM_PAGETYPE_CART;
        $remarketingData['ecomm_prodid'] = $this->getProductIds();
        $remarketingData['ecomm_totalvalue'] = number_format($this->getCartTotal(), 2, '.', '');
        $this->setDataLayerOption('google_tag_params', $remarketingData);
    endif;

    ?>
```

How can I clear that error?

Comment: `$crosselProductsCollection = $this->getCrosselProductCollection() ?? [];`

Comment: Just went in and checked and that cleared it. You can put it as an answer and I will mark it as solved. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how WeltPixel\GoogleTagManager\Helper\Data::getCrosselProductCollection looks exactly as it is a paid extension, but you can add a null coalesce operator to guard the return value to a countable interface implementor such as an array:

`$crosselProductsCollection = $this->getCrosselProductCollection() ?? [];`